Одновременный запрос нескольких пользователей
Я пытаюсь сделать функцию регистрации пользователей на мероприятие через телеграм-бота. При тестировании я заметил кое-что странное.
Дело в том, что если бот получает одновременно два запроса отзыва регистрации от разных пользователей, то он принимает запрос одного пользователя, а другого — нет.
Причём при одновременной регистрации пользователей ничего подобного не наблюдается.
Код функции отзыва регистрации:
@bot.message_handler(commands=["unregistration"])
def unregistration(message):
    user = message.from_user.id
    file = open('users.txt', 'r').read()
    if str(user) in str(file):
        new_data = file.replace(str(user) + '\n', '')
        file = open('users.txt', 'w')
        file.write(new_data)
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Вы были успешно отозвали регистрацию на конкурс. Уведомления приходить вам не будут"
                                               , parse_mode='Markdown')
    else:
        print(str(user))
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Вы не зарегистрированы на конкурс. Зарегистрируйтесь с помощью команды /registration", parse_mode='Markdown')

Если есть возможность исправить данный казус, не переписывая на aiogram, то был бы очень признателен, если бы вы подсказали как.

Ну как минимум файлы после записи нужно закрывать

Спасибо! Проблема действительно была в этом. Теперь всё работает

А как максимум всё равно всё сломается в многопоточной среде, если два запроса попытаются записать/прочитать один и тот же файл одновременно. А сейчас у вас всё работает только на той случайности, что «одновременные» запросы на самом деле не совсем одновременные

Могут ли в таком случае спасти SQL-запросы?

Можно к примеру ставить все входящие запросы в очередь и в отдельном потоке забирать по 1 элементу из неё и записывать ‍♀️
